# Galerkin projection method

Tags: matlab

Does anyone have a working and optimal implementation of the **Galerkin projection method** in Matlab? I tried to implement the method itself, but for some reason, the result didn't converge with the analytical solution.
I've found the realisation of the method on the official Mathworks' [web site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20387-ode-solver-through-galerkin-method/content/odegalerkin/odegalerkin.m) But it does not works. Does anybody know how to run this code correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, but there are two excellent books on discontinuous Galerkin methods and their implementations in general:

http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+%26+engineering/book/978-0-387-72065-4

http://books.google.de/books/about/Implementing_Spectral_Methods_for_Partia.html?id=fZyqWPNjx4AC

Both books include code snippets - the first one (yellow book by Hesthaven/Warburton) uses actual Matlab code, the second one only pseudo code.